# Linux assembly; bss section memory initialized to 0?

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

In tests I have run the memory in the bss section of my programs has always been initialized to zero before I write anything there.  Is this coincidental, or is the system "cleaning" these memory pages before handing them to me?  I am using the nasm assembler on Ubuntu (if that possibly makes a difference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application's executable file(ELF) has a BSS section's size information, when it starts up, kernel allocate a block of memory for BSS section, and clean it to 0. This defined by ABI(Application Binary Interface), so you needn't worry about there are different on different machine.

Comment: Thanks, found the reference for this using your answer: http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/specialsections.html  For linux systems this appears specified in the linux standards base.

Answer (score 0):

Yes BSS is initialized to zero.

Comment: Do you have any canonical *(in the lower-case sense)* reference for that?

Comment: well, man gcc says that variables initialized to zero are placed in the BSS, so in order for this to be legal, the BSS must be initialized to zero.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I found a reference for this using @Huang F. Lei's answer.  Reference is the Linux Standard Base, specifically at page: http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/LSB_4.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/specialsections.html